# Halachot of Communal Wedding Rings

Tags: halacha, marriage, transactions

Ruth Gay writes in her book on German Jewry ([*Jews of Germany*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0300060521)) that in most of the Rheinland communities, a communal wedding ring would be used. Given that the kinyan must be done with something unconditionally owned by the groom and the item used for kinyan subsequently becomes the property of the bride,* communal rings seem not to work well.

Given these concerns, what are the halachot of communal wedding rings and how were they used for centuries without becoming an issue ?

---

*See [this article](https://www.torahmusings.com/2019/05/marriage-the-ring/) on Torah Musings

Comment: Perhaps this was by the reform?

Comment: @GershonGold, extant communal wedding rings date in some cases to the rishonic period, so I doubt it

Comment: https://asif.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/avn-6-8.pdf

Comment: @GershonGold, further, by the time that we see the first development of liberal Judaism, German kehillot were in a much better financial position, presumably obviating the need for such an institution